# Res.redirect() loads as a fetch instead of redirecting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I have a simple fetch that happens after clicking a button to like a post:

```
function like(post_id){
    fetch(`/like/${post_id}`);
}

router.get('/like/:post_id/', authController.isLoggedIn, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    //liking

    req.flash("flash", 'You liked the post!');
    return res.redirect('back');
  }
  catch{
    req.flash("flash", 'Like failed :(');
    return res.redirect('back');
  }
});
```

In theory this should do its thing and then redirect back to the same page with the flash message.

Instead of doing that it loads the page with the fash message as afetch request I never called for!

It should reload the page to act/terrain/... not load it on the side. What's my problem? Do I need to end the fetch somehow before redirecting?

[image]

Comment: `fetch()` calls do not by themselves change the page in the browser, no matter what the response is, even if the response is a redirect.  They just dutifully deliver that redirect response status code and headers back to your Javascript that called the `fetch()`.  It's up to your Javascript to do something with that response.  The browser does not do anything automatically with that response.  The browser only acts on the response if it's from a browser-submitted form or a browser-submitted URL bar request.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake is using fetch in the first place. This is how I got it to work:

```
function like(post_id){
    document.body.innerHTML += `<form id="jsForm" action="/like/${post_id}" method="GET"><input type="hidden" name="a" value="a"></form>`;
    document.getElementById("jsForm").submit();
}
```